# how to call a helper method from both view and controller in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, helper

I created a helper method for some simple calculation. This helper method will just return an integer. I need the helper in both controllers and views.

Unfortunately, it work well in views but not in controllers. I get the `undefined local variable or method` error. How can I fix it?

Thanks all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**In order to use same methods in both controller and views Add you method in application_controller.rb and make it helper methods**.

For example

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time
  #protect_from_forgery # See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details
  helper_method :current_user 

  def current_user
    session[:user]
  end

end
```

Now you can use method **current_user** in both controllers & views

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! :)

Comment: A note about this example: since `helper :all` defines all public methods as helpers, there is no need for both `helper :all` and `helper_method :current_user`. It's an either/or proposition.

Answer (score 4):

I use a following solution. Because I think helper's methods shoud be stored in an appropriate helper module.

```
module TestHelper
  def my_helper_method
    #something
  end
end


class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    template.my_helper_method
  end
end
```

Comment: I prefer this solution to the chosen one. But, minor change with the latest rails: SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300582/rails-3-template-variable-inside-controllers-is-nil  you need to use view_context instead of @template.