# Rails 3: @template variable inside controllers is nil

Tags: templates, helper, ruby-on-rails-3

i've started using rails 3 beta3 and I have see that the @template variable inside controllers is nil. How I can call helpers methods inside a controller? Thx

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `view_context` method instead of `@template`.

This is because in Rails 3 the new `AbstractController` was introduced.

You can read more here:

http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/view_context

Comment: Hello, I am having problems with [ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272814/passing-actionviewhelpersformbuilder-to-a-partial). Could you paste a working example of how to use view_context. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what do you want to do, but if you want to render a form into a string in your controller you could do it like this:
form_string = view_context.form_for(Article.new){|f| f.text_field :title; f.text_field :body }