# Rails 3: @template variable inside controllers is nil

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, helper, controllers

I have the same problem, as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300582/rails-3-template-variable-inside-controllers-is-nil) question. Did anybody find any solutions for this?

So I can't do like this:

```
flash[:notice] = "Successfully created #{@template.link_to('product', @product)}.
```

or like this:

```
@template.title("Page title is here.")
```

It worked perfectly in Rails 2.3. The main idea is to find out, how to use helper methods directly from conrollers, not from views.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't use helper methods from controllers, you use them in views...

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong.

First, you should setup the title of a page inside the view, not in your controller.
You can simply place a call to the `title` helper within your view file.

About the link, flash shouldn't contain HTML. However, you can create the link manually.

```
flash[:notice] = %Q{Successfully created <a href="#{product_path(@product)}">product</a>.}
```

Comment: I know, that I can do it inside my view. But the question was, that I can't find variable similar to @template in Rails 2.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem as well and found that you can use the view_context method.

API documentation here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html#method-i-view_context