# Rails 3- fixing juggernaut involving template and JS generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller, juggernaut

I'm using the original [Juggernaut](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/) (not [Juggernaut 2](http://github.com/maccman/juggernaut)) with Rails 3. In the lib/juggernaut.rb, it breaks due to not being able to find `@template`. According to this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300582/rails-3-template-variable-inside-controllers-is-nil), `@template` is not provided in controllers in Rails 3.

How can I fix the following code, so that it can run smoothly with Rails 3? (Here's a link to the [original script](http://github.com/maccman/juggernaut_plugin/blob/master/lib/juggernaut.rb). Look for `render_with_juggernaut`.)

```
      if @template.respond_to?(:_evaluate_assigns_and_ivars, true)
        @template.send(:_evaluate_assigns_and_ivars)
      else
        @template.send(:evaluate_assigns)
      end

      generator = ActionView::Helpers::PrototypeHelper::JavaScriptGenerator.new(@template, &block)            
      render_for_juggernaut(generator.to_s, options.is_a?(Hash) ? options[:juggernaut] : nil)
```

I'm thinking one of two things can be done:

- get a hold of @template somehow
- produce a snippet of JS without
  involving JavaScriptGenerator (which
  requires @template)

Do you have any suggestions on how to do one of these or other ways?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What's the reason you're not using Juggernaut 2? Legacy support?

Comment: Actually I ended up using Juggernaut 2. The problem above seems like an interesting one still.