# Helpers in controller - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, helper, controllers

I migrated from rails 2.x to 3.x. Now when calling a controller method throws

> ```
> undefined method `my_helper_method' for nil:NilClass
> ```

MyController.rb

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
    def foo
      @template.my_helper_method
    end
end
```

MyControllerHelper.rb

```
class MyControllerHelper
    def my_helper_method
      puts "Hello"
    end
end
```

ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   helper :all
end
```

How to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually answered in another SO post: [Rails 3: @template variable inside controllers is nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300582/rails-3-template-variable-inside-controllers-is-nil)

Essentially, you can replace `@template` with `view_context`

Answer (score 1):

`@template` is an object, in your case `nil`. If this object doesn't has the method (`my_helper_method`) in it, you cannot call it (especially not if it is nil).

Methods defined in helpers are called like regular methods. But not in controllers, they are called in views. Your `helper :all` just makes all helpers available to the views.

So, in your view: `my_helper_method :arg1, :arg2`

IF you need a method for your object (`@template`), you need to give your object this method.

**Example:**

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base

  def my_helper_method
    # do something on a template instance
  end

end


class MyController < ApplicationController
  def foo
    @template = Template.first
    @template.my_helper_method # which actually isn't a helper
  end
end
```

**What helpers do:**

```
module MyHelper
  def helper_method_for_template(what)
  end
end

# in your view
helper_method_for_template(@template)
```

**Mixing in a helper (be aware of having a mess in your code when mixing view helpers with views and models)**

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyHelper

  # Now, there is @template.helper_method_for_template(what) in here. 
  # This can get messy when you are making your helpers available to your
  # views AND use them here. So why not just write the code in here where it belongs
  # and leave helpers to the views? 
end
```

Comment: But you are migrating to rails3. I don't know why it is working, but helpers are supposed to help in your views. If you want to include helpers in your controller, do `include MyControllerHelper` in your controller. However, these are still "usual" methods and not instance methods for an object ( e.g. `@template`). You could make them available for this object when mixing in the helper methods into your Model/Instance Base. But this would not really follow the convention.

Comment: you are better off `migrating` and not `patching-everything-so-the-old-things-which-are-not-good-are-still-working`. If you really want to do the second one, stay on rails 2.x. I updated the answer, have a look. What you want is to define those methods inside your Model or whatever `@template` is created of.